# if $g:X\to[0,1] $ is a continuous function,then $g^{-1}(0)$ is a $G_\delta$-set in $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ is a topological space and $g:X\to[0,1] $ is a continuous function, is true that $g^{-1}(0)$ is a $G_\delta$-set in $X$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, because $\{0\}=\bigcap_{n>0} [0,\frac1n)$ is a $G_\delta$ set in $[0,1]$.  So,
$$g^{-1}(\{0\})=\bigcap_{n>0} g^{-1}([0,\frac1n))$$expresses $g^{-1}(\{0\})$ as a countable intersection of open sets in $X$.

Comment: And in a $T_4$ space $X$ the reverse is true as well: every closed $G_\delta$ set $A$ can be written as $A = g^{-1}[\{0\}]$ for some continuous $g: X \rightarrow [0,1]$.